# AWS target group reports unhealthy, but application is healthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have an IIS website running in AWS on an EC2 instance, running on http://localhost:8088. It is behind an ELB that sends all HTTPS traffic to the target group that the EC2 instance is running in, so any request to http://my-dns-name gets rerouted by the ELB to https://my-dns-name, and then on to the target group. I have a health check defined on the target group that checks the `/healthcheck` endpoint for a 200 OK response, and the endpoint is configured to allow unauthenticated requests (aka anonymous).

The application itself is running fine; however, AWS is reporting the target group as unhealthy as it is receiving a response code of 302 from the health check endpoint. If I query the endpoint myself directly from my desktop e.g. via PowerShell's `Invoke-WebRequest` then I get the expected `200 OK` response. If I remote into the EC2 instance and run the same query then it also returns the expected `200 OK` response.

```
$> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://my-dns-name/healthcheck -Method GET
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

But if I change it to use the local address of `http://localhost:8088`, then the query fails:

```
$> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:8088/healthcheck -Method GET
Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:8088/healthcheck -Method GET
```

Any ideas why the target group is getting a 302 redirect, but if I query directly then I get 200 OK (unless I use the local address)?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this was a coding issue with the application; there was a `RequireHttps` filter buried deep in the application start-up code, that was obviously trying doing a redirect in the background; AWS was checking the website using HTTP and thus experiencing the 302 redirect, but when I was checking externally I was going over HTTPS which didn't trigger the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check here:

1. Is the Windows firewall running and blocking port 8088?
2. Is IIS actually listening on 8088?
3. Is your AWS TG set up to do the healthcheck on 8088?, It looks like it's running on port 443 given the 200 OK response on https.

Comment: I've figured out the issue (see separate answer), but in response to your questions:

1. No, Windows Firewall isn't running;
2. IIS is listening on 8088
3. AWS TG is configured to check on 8088